# Assembly uses version X which has a higher version than referenced assembly error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, conflicting-libraries

After upgrading from ASP.NET Core 2.0 to 2.1-preview2 I got the following error:

```
Error   CS1705  Assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient' with identity 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' uses 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Runtime' with identity 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
```

When I look around for similar errors, I see a lot of discussions about the versions that are referenced in csproj or json files (depending how old the discussion is). But in .NET Core there is only one reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`. So, I don't have any way to manipulate the references to either `System.Data.SqlClient` or `System.Runtime`

Another observation that while most errors refer to real code like `connection.Open()` there are two references to non-existent file CSC line 1.

**UPDATE**: if I create a new project and copy the offending code there, I am *not* getting any errors. So, apparently the references to the mismatching versions are somewhere in the project... but I can't figure out where!

Comment: It looks like the `System.Data.SqlClient` assembly has a dependency on  assembly `System.Runtime, Version=4.2.1.0`. Your project is using assembly `System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0`.

Comment: ok. and? can I fix it? I don't include either one explicitly; just `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.0-preview2-final"`

Comment: Look at the target .NET Framework for the project. That is why a new project works out of the box.

Comment: It's 2.1 for all

Answer (score 8):

Had the same issue. Resolved by locating **RuntimeFrameworkVersion** tag in **.csproj** file and changing it's value to **2.1**.

Comment: I also had the same issue, but a different cause. I was incorrectly including a library 'Z' targeting dotnet core 2.1 into a library 'Y' targeting dotnet standard 2.0, that was included in the final app 'X' targeting dotnet core 2.1. The compiler really didn't like this, but the error messages was cryptic, (the same as in original question). Refactoring the 'middle' library in the chain ZYX to dotnet core 2.1 fixed it. I realize this sounds obvious, but I was given Z and Y and they all worked on their own. Your question has only  one library, I post this for others who may have this problem

Comment: for core 2.2.1 change this to 2.2

Answer (score 2):

Using Visual Studio, the easiest way is:

1.- Right-click on the solution and go to "Manager Nugget Packages for solution..."

2.- Go to "Consolidate tab" (The last on the right side)
You will see the different versions of assemblies on each project.

- Try to unify the version for all project references within your solution.
  (Uninstall and install the same version).

Good Luck!!

Comment: Thanks, David. It was a single-project solution; so your suggestion doesn't apply. Anyway, the issue is 3.5 years old and we solved it by creating a new project and just moving code as I indicated in the update. Probably a bug in Microsoft's beta version

Comment: Actually, it happened to me in the morning and that's why I posted the solution that helped me out to solve the issue. ;)